# RotateAnimation without duration

Tags: android, animation, rotation

guys. i have this code (asyncTask)

my animation() function :

```
public void animation()
        {
        int   currentRotation = 0;
            anim = new RotateAnimation(currentRotation, (360*4),
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
            currentRotation = (currentRotation + 45) % 360;
            anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            anim.setDuration(4000);// i want rotating without this <------------------
            anim.setFillEnabled(true);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            refresh.startAnimation(anim);
        }
```

Can anyone tell me it's possible to do it without `anim.setDuration` ????
just only start .. and when  i pressed on button(for example) animation stoped. 
Please help me.
 Regards, Peter.

final code :

```
 public void animation()
            {
            int   currentRotation = 0;
                anim = new RotateAnimation(currentRotation, (360*4),
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
                currentRotation = (currentRotation + 45) % 360;
                anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                anim.setDuration(4000);
               // anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
                anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                anim.setFillEnabled(true);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                refresh.startAnimation(anim);
            }
```

and somewhere   `refresh.clearAnimation();` for stop animation 
it's work perfect for me .. if here some thing wrong - please tell me .. Anyway thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you should look at repeat mode. The duration is the time for one loop through the animation, if you set it up to repeat after that, then it can go on forever. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setRepeatMode%28int%29) and [that](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setRepeatCount%28int%29).

For instance, you could use:

```
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
```

Answer (score 1):

As PearsonArtPhoto suggested, you should look at repeat mode. The duration is the time for one loop through the animation, if you set it up to repeat after that, then it can go on forever.

Use ObjectAnimator to achieve result.
For instance, you could use:

```
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART); //note the difference here
```